# Global Traffic Director - On DO droplet with Ubuntu, LAMP and Nginx help needed

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, lamp, geoip

I have been trying to follow Digital Ocean following exemple:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-nginx-as-a-global-traffic-director-on-debian-or-ubuntu

Having set a droplet with Ubuntu and there LAMP stack already.

Despite having configured on top of the LAMP stack an Nginx to try to use the GeoIP database, when I run a test.php file that has in it the following code:

```
 <?php
     if (getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR)) {
        $sname = getenv(SERVER_NAME);
        $sipaddress = getenv(SERVER_ADDR);
        $pipaddress = getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR);
        $ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
        echo "$sname server has address : $sipaddress";
        echo "<br />\n";
        echo "Your Proxy IP address is : ".$pipaddress. " (via $ipaddress) " ;
    } else {
        $servername = getenv(SERVER_NAME);
        $serveripaddress = getenv(SERVER_ADDR);
        $ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
        echo "$servername server has address : $serveripaddress";
        echo "<br />\n";
        echo "Your IP address is : $ipaddress";
    }
    $country = getenv(GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME);
    $country_code = getenv(GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE);
    echo "<br/>Your country : $country ( $country_code ) ";
?>
```

I get the following response live:

```
www.mydomain.com server has address : 12.34.56.78
Your IP address is : 87.65.43.21
Your country : ( )
```

As you can see the IP address are correct which shows that PHP works fine but unfortunately none of the GEOIP variables are working despite being locally present.

So the question I have are:

- **Where did I screw up?**
- **How come the GeoIP data is not passing through Nginx?**

---

Here are some extra steps I took to configure the servers.

I renamed the default config file from /etc/nginx/sites-available to my domain name and made sure create a new link to it in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled.

Then my config file looks like this at the moment:

```
map $geoip_city_continent_code $closest_server {
  default eu.mydomain.com;
  US      US.mydomain.com;
  AS      as.mydomain.com;
}

server {

server_name mydomain.com
            www.mydomain.com
            eu.mydomain.com
            us.mydomain.com
            as.mydomain.com;

if ($closest_server != $host) {
  rewrite ^ $scheme://$closest_server$request_uri break;
}

listen 80 eu.mydomain.com;
listen [::]:80 eu.mydomain.com ipv6only=on;

root /var/www/html;
index index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name localhost;
```

The end goal is to have 3 servers ( USA, Europe, Asia ), have the EU one being central and reroute to the closest server using either: us.mydomain.com or eu.mydomain.com or as.mydomain.com

I hope this is clear enough any pointers would be great!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: So I changed my stack to LEMP, and followed these additional steps with regards to fastcgi_param http://piwik.org/faq/how-to/faq_166/

Comment: That allowed me to successfully see where my call was based from: Your country : United States ( US ), but unfortunately if I call the europe server, it does not automatically reroute me back to the US server... Any Ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a LEMP stack instead when building the droplet and spotted some missing information from the Digital Ocean documents which are as follows:

Add both of these lines in the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file:

- geoipcountry /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;
- geoipcity /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat;

Then in the /etc/nginx/fastcgiparams add at the end:

```
fastcgiparam REDIRECTSTATUS 200;
fastcgiparam GEOIPADDR $remoteaddr;
fastcgiparam GEOIPCOUNTRYCODE $geoipcountrycode;
fastcgiparam GEOIPCOUNTRYNAME $geoipcountryname;
fastcgiparam GEOIPREGION $geoipregion;
fastcgiparam GEOIPREGIONNAME $geoipregionname;
fastcgiparam GEOIPCITY $geoipcity;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_CITY_CONTINENT_CODE $geoip_city_continent_code; #EDIT
fastcgiparam GEOIPAREACODE $geoipareacode;
fastcgiparam GEOIPLATITUDE $geoiplatitude;
fastcgiparam GEOIPLONGITUDE $geoiplongitude;
fastcgiparam GEOIPPOSTALCODE $geoippostal_code;
```

Then in the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default the distinction between each servers within the default files is also handled at the map $geoipcountrycode $closest_server { level as follows:

**EDITS!!**

US server:

```
map $geoip_city_continent_code $closest_server {
  default www.yourdomain.com;

  AF      eu.yourdomain.com;  #Africa
  AS      as.yourdomain.com;  #Asia
  EU      eu.yourdomain.com;  #Europe
  # NA      www.yourdomain.com;  #North America
  OC      as.yourdomain.com;  #Oceania
  # SA      www.yourdomain.com;  #South America
}
```

Europe Server:

```
map $geoip_city_continent_code $closest_server {
  default eu.yourdomain.com;

  # AF      eu.yourdomain.com;  #Africa
  AS      as.yourdomain.com;  #Asia
  # EU      eu.yourdomain.com;  #Europe
  NA      www.yourdomain.com;  #North America
  OC      as.yourdomain.com;  #Oceania
  SA      www.yourdomain.com;  #South America
}
```

Asia Server :

```
map $geoip_city_continent_code $closest_server {
  default as.yourdomain.com;

  AF      eu.yourdomain.com;  #Africa
  # AS      as.yourdomain.com;  #Asia
  EU      eu.yourdomain.com;  #Europe
  NA      www.yourdomain.com;  #North America
  # OC      as.yourdomain.com;  #Oceania
  SA      www.yourdomain.com;  #South America
}
```

And that should do it...

You can also test your setup by adding a test.php file that has the following code in the body:

```
<?php
if (getenv(HTTPXFORWARDEDFOR)) {
  $pipaddress = getenv(HTTPXFORWARDEDFOR);
  $ipaddress = getenv(REMOTEADDR);
  echo "Your Proxy IP address is : ".$pipaddress. " (via $ipaddress) " ;
} else {
  $ipaddress = getenv(REMOTEADDR);
  echo "Your IP address is : $ipaddress";
}
$country = getenv(GEOIPCOUNTRYNAME);
$countrycode = getenv(GEOIPCOUNTRYCODE);
$geoip_city_continent_code = getenv(GEOIP_CITY_CONTINENT_CODE);
echo "<br/>Your country : $country ( $countrycode ) ";
echo "<br/>Your continent : $geoip_city_continent_code ";
?>
```

Which should return something like this:

```
Your IP address is : 12.34.56.78
Your country : United States ( US )
Your continent : NA
```

If you are in the USA and reroute you to the www.yourdomain.com etc....

**EDIT 2 - For multisite handling**

This is structured to serve different servers with a country code for subdomain in this case the us.domain.com for the us server...

```
map $geoip_city_continent_code $closest_server {
  AF      eu.domain.com;  #Africa
  AS      as.domain.com;  #Asia
  EU      eu.domain.com;  #Europe
  NA      us.domain.com;  #North America
  OC      as.domain.com;  #Oceania
  SA      us.domain.com;  #South America
}

# retoute http://domain.com and http://www.domain.com to http://us.domain.com
server {

  listen 80 default_server; # only for one of the local domains other wise the others should only be: listen 80;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; # only for one of the local domains other wise the others should only be: listen [::]:80;

  server_name domain.com
              www.domain.com;

  return 301 http://us.domain.com$request_uri;
}

# handles
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  root /var/www/domain.com/html;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
  server_name  us.domain.com;

  # firs part of dual condition check.
  # checks in the incoming host (us.domain.com) is not equal to $closest_server depending on contry code
  if ($closest_server != $host) {
    set $test  A;
  }

  #second part of dual condition checks that the incoming host us.domain.com is the same as the server_name so that there is no messing around with other domain names
  if ($host ~* $server_name) {
    set $test  "${test}B";
  }

  # checks that the above 2 conditions are met and if so redirect to other global server with appropriate subdomain eu.domain.com or whatever you set up
  if ($test = AB) {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$closest_server$request_uri break;
  }

  # otherwise you are at the closest server and so serve the data
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
```